# URL filtering using driver for OS X

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extension

I have an requirement for my client, where in i need to block particular URL based on the user input.
I was thinking to implement this by building a driver, From which i can get the packet response with all the details through this I can block/allow by building an application.(THIS is similar to what "netfilter" driver does in windows)

But as i read through the docs and websites i did not get enough information to proceed with for this particular requirement.(I found about bpf but there was not enough details to proceed with)

As I am very much NEW to the driver field,Can someone suggest me how to proceed in this case.(Steps how to proceed)

Note:I found lot of projects/docs related to USB drivers and all but they were not giving enough idea to proceed for further.

Answer (score 1):

"URL" is very broad, and depending on the kinds of URL (what protocols? What about encryption?) and required granularity, some other solution than a custom kext might be a better approach. Not knowing your requirements, I can't say whether that's the case.

What I **can** answer, however, is that if you **do** decide to do this from a kext, [Network Kernel Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/intro/intro.html) are what you need to look into.

Apple also provides [the enetlognke example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/enetlognke/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003579) to illustrate how to use the NKE APIs.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion, i took URL just as an example but concentrating mainly on packet based control and example you suggested helped me a lot to understand the concept. As i am aware of kext, i would like to proceed with the same.

Comment: However logs which gets printed is in the format 
[...] enetlognke out IPv4 a820662e49ca|000c29f281ec|0800|45000054   98 but i was unable to retrieve source and destination ip from above mentioned output.(I tried to convert  this hex value  to a820662e49ca to ip format but it always gave wrong ip details).
Is any method is there to convert the above values.

Comment: `a820662e49ca` looks like a MAC address. (Vendor: Apple) The code comments in the example around where this output is printed indicate that the packets are ethernet frames - so you most likely need to first find where the IP packet starts, then check its header.

Comment: I was able to identify source and destination ip addresses after analyzing the payload but i observed that only "ping command" packets are getting logged but TCP packets generated via browser are not getting logged.
Is there any ways to get those packets too or Am i missing something here.

Comment: Note that the `enetlognke` example is an interface filter, attached by `iflt_attach()` - it will only log packets traversing the network interface specified by `gNameOfInterfaceToFilter` (en0 by default). Are you sure that's the case for the packets you're trying to filter? For IP-level filtering, consider using socket filters (see `sflt_register()`) or IP packet filters (see `ipf_addv4()`/`ipf_addv6`) instead, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @pmdj netfiltersdk.com provides a paid/demo sdk for network filtering on windows. is there any one who provide the network filtering sdk for Mac OS; because I am finding a way to develop kext for ad/url blocking.

Comment: @vikramsingh I haven't used it myself, but perhaps the [NEFilter Network Extension API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nefiltermanager?language=objc) can be used for what you're trying to do. Another popular option are browser plugins. Alternatively, you can try to go with the network kernel extension (NKE) approach mentioned in the answer, although this will limit you to filtering IP addresses and to some extent host names, as a lot of traffic is nowadays encrypted with TLS, which hides the full URL from the network. I'm not aware of an SDK built on top of NKE.

Comment: Like @pmdj is already written, writing URL filtering using KEXT is complex. Raw IP traffic is received at KEXT and figuring out the domain/host of IP address is complex. You need to figure-out IP address to hostname mapping or parsing the right packet(TLS case: Client hello and figuring out hostname, HTTP case: Request packet)  to get hostname still you may not figure out the right hostname in many scenarios.   You may need to write browser extension which will simplify your work. There are more complex options available like writing your local proxy but it will depend upon your requirement.